# Labelling big serialized data in R (fst & Hmisc)

Tags: r, serialization, label, bigdata, hmisc

I have a question about how to save labeled data when using the `fst` package.
I've been using the `Hmisc` package to label data, such as:

```
library(fst)
library(Hmisc)

# make an example dataset
df <- data.frame(id = letters[1:4],
                 val = 1:4)

# apply labels to dataframe
label(df$id) <- "identifier"
label(df$val) <- "value"

label(df)
         id          val 
"identifier"      "value"
```

But my actual data is quite large, so I've switched to saving it as `fst` rather than `rds`. Recently, though, I've noticed that this appears to make my labels disappear:

```
fp <- '~/filepath/example_code_data/label_ex.fst'

# save as fst
write_fst(df, fp)

# open data again
df2 <- read_fst(fp)

label(df2)
 id val 
 ""  ""
```

When I save the data as an `rds` I have no issues with the labels. Any more insight into what's going on or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who has a similar issue in the future, it appears this is a [known bug](https://github.com/fstpackage/fst/issues/256) of `fst`. One helpful commentator on that thread suggests `qs` as a similar package that retains labels, although I'm remiss to lose `fst`'s random column access, among other nice features.